# Are there other sites such as Rome2Rio?

Tags: air-travel, trains, online-resources, planning, transportation

I have been solely relying on [Rome2Rio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome2rio) (click the link for a quick explanation of what Rome2Rio is) for planning transportation around Europe. However, only recently have I noticed that it doesn't provide complete information. For example, some TGV routes aren't included and I've had to find routes through other websites. Are there other websites similar to Rome2Rio or is there a more complete version of such a site?

Comment: it's not really the same (there is no mix trains/planes) but to have tgv routes, try http://mytripset.voyages-sncf.com/#/search/FR_fr

Comment: You can't assume we all know this site, or know it as well as you do. You should tell us briefly what it does and especially what features it has (or lacks) are the ones you need.

Comment: TGV routes will soon be available through SNCF OpenData portal: http://www.nextinpact.com/news/93038-la-sncf-va-mettre-ses-horaires-tgv-en-open-data.htm

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm Chris from Rome2Rio, if you don't mind sharing your experience we'd be keen to find out which TGV routes and European routes in general you have found are missing from Rome2Rio results. This would help us review and improve our results in future. If you prefer you can send the details to feedback@rome2rio.com

If you are looking for alternatives to Rome2Rio you could also try [routerank](http://www.routerank.com/en/) along with the Voyage SCNF site already mentioned.  Also there are a couple more German focused sites with similar concepts GoEuro and [Waymate](https://www.waymate.de/en/searches) in the future they may expand to feature other European countries in their data.

Some other sites that you may already be aware of that I'd recommend would be Bahn a comprehensive schedule planner along with Seat 61 which has good references and guides to travelling by train in Europe.

There also several nice sites using the Rome2Rio API, but as it is generally the same dataset as Rome2Rio you may not be as interested in those :)

Comment: +1, Love it when site owners come and engage in a useful manner, and aren't afraid to show alternatives.

Comment: I also recently heard of https://www.kenavo.com/

Comment: When I travelled in the Balkans, I found some bus routes missing from Rome2Rio database. I wrote to them with all the information needed and Chris answered that they appreciated the info. Unfortunately, **they have not added anything to the database 3 months since**.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding [GoEuro](http://www.goeuro.com) for europe is important, specially because you can do booking. Note that I work for the company.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Are you in any way affiliated with GoEuro?